# How to send data from server to client continuously with Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4

I am using the Qt fortune server example of a client-server implementation. In this example the server sends a random fortune when there is a new connection and then closes the connection. But for my program I want the server to continuously communicate with the client once the client has connected. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two approaches here:

1. You don't close the connection. When client connects to the server the connection is maintained until either client or server shuts down. This way both client and server can initiate requests at any time. You will need to implement some pinging mechanism where client and server will send small requests periodically just to notify each other that they're still "alive". When these stop incoming then the connection is shut down. Client must be prepared for this to happen at any time and re-establish the connection if the shutdown was unexpected.
2. Implement this using REST architecture: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restful . This is the same model that browsers use to fetch WWW sites. Each time client wants something from the server it instantiates a new connection, sends the request, receives the response and shuts down the connection. Naturally, if connection needs to be re-established all the time it may hit the performance, therefore clients should maintain the connections alive until they decide they're no longer needed or the keep alive time expires. This is actually implemented in Internet browsers. Remember that this architecture prevents you from sending requests from the server to the client directly. If client needs to refresh information in real time it will need to continuously ask the server for it in short periods.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do not disconnect clients and store client sockets returned by `QTcpServer::nextPendingConnection()` to use them later.

Answer (score 0):

There are many projects in [Gitorious](https://gitorious.org/) or in [Github](https://github.com/) (and many other sites), which can serve you an example, but not exactly what you are looking for, a little studying and documenting these projects, you can see how other developers get to make your own study their profession.

I really comes to mind an interesting project that meets in full their idea [**QtWebsocket**](https://gitorious.org/qtwebsocket), but of course must always consider how to apply that, for your needs.